# How to set Microsoft Egde as jupyter notebook browser?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I set `c.NotebookApp.browser = u'start microsoft-edge:%s'` in jupyter_notebook_config.py, but did not work.

How to set Microsoft Egde as jupyter notebook browser?